# How do I select subset of images from Android gallery without explicit selection? The selection should be automatic based on image meta-data

Tags: android, image, mediastore

How do I select subset of images from Android gallery without explicit selection? The selection of images should be automatic based on image meta-data. 
**I do not want to be routed to the gallery activity for explicitly picking images. The subset of images should be auto-fetched based on a filter criteria. Suppose I say select all images from my gallery with the date when maximum number of photos were clicked. The android app would then display all images from the gallery that meet this criteria (max number of images with same date stamp).**

I haven't been able to find any solution so far that does these two things:
1) Allows me to get images from gallery without explicit selection/picking from gallery
2) Allows me to auto-select images based on location and date meta-data

Please help, super stuck. Point me to any useful resources. Thank you.

Comment: Have you found any solution for that ?

Comment: Have you had any developments?